# Assigning words a unique number identifier

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

**Task**

I am trying to assign an number identifier for words in a string.

**Code**

I have currently done the following:

```
mystr = 'who are you you are who'

str_values = mystr.split()
list_values = [str(i) for i, w in enumerate(mystr.split())]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> str_values
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> list_values
['who', 'are', 'you', 'you', 'are', 'who']
```

**Query/Desired Output**

`mystr` contains repeating words, and so I would like to assign each word a number rather than different numbers each time but aren't sure how I should begin doing so. Therefore, I would like `list_values` to output something along the line of:

```
['0', '1', '2', '2', '1', '0']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with help of another list -

```
n = []
output = [n.index(i) for i in mystr.split() if i in n or not n.append(i)]
```

First `n` is empty list. Now list comprehension iterate over all the element of `mystr.split()`. It adds the index of the element in list `n` if condition met.

Now for the condition. There are two parts with an `or`. First it checks if the element is present in `n`. If yes, then get the index of the element. If no, it goes to the second part, which just appends the element to the list `n`. Now `append()` returns `None`. That is why I added a not before it. So, that condition will be satisfied and it will give the newly inserted elements index.

Basically the first part of if condition restricts duplicate element addition in `n` and the second part does the addition.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, An explanation would be even better =)

Comment: @LearningToPython, added the explanation

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much =)

Comment: @LearningToPython, one thing I forget is to convert index to string. I think you can do that if you really need it

Answer (score 1):

Well we can work in two phases:

- first we construct a dictionary that maps words on indices, given they do not exist yet, and
- next we use the dictionary to obtain the word identifiers.

Like:

```
identifiers = {}
idx = 0
for word in mystr.split():
    if word not in identifiers:
        identifiers[word] = idx
        idx += 1

list_values = [identifiers[word] for word in mystr.split()]
```

This generates:

```
>>> [identifiers[word] for word in mystr.split()]
[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```

If you want, you can also convert the identifiers to strings, with `str(..)`, but I do not see why wou would do that:

```
>>> [str(identifiers[word]) for word in mystr.split()]
['0', '1', '2', '2', '1', '0']
```

The algorithm will usually work in *O(n)*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a dictionary to keep track of which words have already been seen

```
word_map = {}
word_id_counter = 0
def word_id(word):
    global word_id_counter
    if word in word_map:
        return word_map[word]
    else:
        word_map[word] = word_id_counter
        word_id_counter += 1
        return word_map[word]
```

To avoid using global variables you can wrap it in a class

```
class WordIdGenerator:
    word_map = {}
    word_id_counter = 0
    def word_id(self, word):
        if word in self.word_map:
            return self.word_map[word]
        else:
            self.word_map[word] = self.word_id_counter
            self.word_id_counter += 1
            return self.word_map[word]
```

And you can use it like this:

```
gen = WordIdGenerator()

[gen.word_id(w) for w in 'who are you you are who'.split()]
```

And the output will be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```